# Convergence of discrete eigenvalues of the heat equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the eigenvalue problem associated with the heat equation
\begin{equation}
\phi''(x) = \lambda \phi(x), \qquad \phi(0)=\phi(1)=1.
\end{equation}
Whilst the eigenvalues can be calculated analytically, I want to calculate them numerically. To do this, consider the finite difference approximation

\begin{equation}
\frac{\phi^{i+1}-2\phi^i+\phi^{i-1}}{h^2}=\lambda \phi^i
\end{equation}
where $i=1,...,N+1$ and $h=1/N$. This can be assembled into the matrix-vector form

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{\phi} = \lambda \boldsymbol{\phi}
\end{equation}
such that $\boldsymbol{\phi} = \big(\phi^2,...,\phi^j,...,\phi^N)^T$ and $\boldsymbol{A} $ is a tri-diagonal matrix of size $(N-1)\times (N-1)$ with $-2/h^2$ on the diagonals and $1/h^2$ on both the lower and upper diagonals. To find the eigenvalues, I use the $\texttt{eig}$ function in matlab, i.e. $\texttt{eig}(A).$

My issue is the following. As I increase $N$ (consequently decreasing the step size, $h$) my eigenvalues do not converge. I have attached a figure illustrating the eigenvalues for $N=100, N=200$ and $N=300$. Why do the eigenvalues not converge? Is there something fundamentally wrong with my formulation, or is there a rational step that I'm missing that maps the eigenvalues calculated numerically to their continuous spectum? I have also found that my eigenvalues diverge like $1/h^2$ as I decrease $h$.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean your eigenvalues or eigenvectors do not converge?  That looks like the plot of one eigenvector (although not with the boundary conditions you want).

Comment: The equation after "...finite difference approximation" contains a typo. You have $\phi^{i+1}$ twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a different graph where we have eigenvalue number on the $x$-axis:

[image: eigenvalues converging]

This picture reveals the right way to understand in what sense eigenvalues converge. For each $k\in\mathbb N$, the sequence consisting of $k$th largest eigenvalue of each matrix with $N>k$ converges to the $k$th largest eigenvalue of the second derivative operator with periodic boundary conditions, which is $-(\pi k)^2$.